# Menu content flipped in RTL language

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu, right-to-left

In project.pbxproj I changed developmentRegion to ar to force Arabic language and RTL layout in entire app. Everything looks good except Menu view content in this example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTime: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("", selection: $selectedTime) {
                Text("صباحاً").tag(0)
                Text("مساءً").tag(1)
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Menu {
                Button("السبت", action: {})
                Button("الأحد", action: {})
                Button("الاثنين", action: {})
                Button("الثلاثاء", action: {})
                Button("الاربعاء", action: {})
                Button("الخميس", action: {})
                Button("الجمعة", action: {})
            } label: {
                Label("اليوم", systemImage: "calendar")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

The buttons' labels inside Menu are flipped.

[image: Menu button label is flipped]

Comment: this happen with English too if developmentRegion is ar, adding .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true) does nothing inside Menu.

Comment: Happens to me as well as SwiftUI lists flip for a second and return to normal… wondering if you got a solution?

Comment: I achieved in the more simpler way. 
Since you can't modify the content directly inside the menu, make another subview and put the RTL code i.e.


`.environment(\.layoutDirection, LanguageHelper.shared.isRightToLeft() ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight)`

and then inside menu call your subview. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can achieve this is change the  language through settings **and** restart the app.

1. Add any language you need in the project settings settings:
   [image: Project settings]
2. You must add the `settings.bundle`:

```
File -> New -> File -> Settings Bundle
```

[image: Settings]

<sub>Delete useless settings if needed</sub>

3. head to the settings and change it:
   [image: Settings]

---

#### Important notes

- I couldn't find any workaround this until now (`18 August 2021`)
- You should ask the user to change the language if preferes and open the settings for them
- You can change the language programatically with:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
```

**BUT!**

- The settings must exist
- The app must restart after the language change
- You can force close the app after settings the language for example with the `exit()` code if the language is not `ar`

---

#### Development note

The simulator constantly caches the settings. So you may face issues that prevent you from seeing the current settings. Try test the flow in test projects and implement the result in the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```swift
init() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
}
```

Here, is the complete code which works

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    }
    
    @State private var selectedTime: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("", selection: $selectedTime) {
                Text("صباحاً").tag(0)
                Text("مساءً").tag(1)
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Menu {
                Button("السبت", action: {})
                Button("الأحد", action: {})
                Button("الاثنين", action: {})
                Button("الثلاثاء", action: {})
                Button("الاربعاء", action: {})
                Button("الخميس", action: {})
                Button("الجمعة", action: {})
            } label: {
                Label("اليوم", systemImage: "calendar")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: same thing, did you do anything else beside the init function?

Comment: Nothing else I did, I just launched it using `Right-to-Left Pseudolanguage` as the App language. [Referenced from this article](https://novinfard.medium.com/make-your-ios-app-compatible-with-right-to-left-languages-in-swiftui-and-uikit-bdb164892ce3)

Comment: I tried all the rtl options for app language in the article nothing worked, I'm curious how did it work for you?

Comment: I was able to replicate it on all devices from iOS 14.5 to 15.0

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me (specially that I've added SwiftUI to UIKit project) is this:

Calling `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(enabled:Bool)` on the views that has the mirroring issue. Passing `true` if the layout is `RTL`.

Something like this:

```
// Step 1: Create View extension for RTL fix
extension View {
    func fixRtl(_ layoutDirection: LayoutDirection) -> some View {
        return self.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.rightToLeft)
    }
}

// Step 2: Add layoutDirection variable to your SwiftUI view
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.layoutDirection) var layoutDirection

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Step 3: Apply fixRtl extension to Text views or their containers
            Text("RTL TEXT النص بالعربي")
                .fixRtl(layoutDirection)
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                // Applying fixRtl to a container
                VStack {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
                .fixRtl(layoutDirection)
                .padding()
                
                // Applying fixRtl directly to a Text view
                Text("Another RTL TEXT النص بالعربي")
                    .fixRtl(layoutDirection)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made it work in my app:

1. Edit scheme > App Language > Arabic (or Right-to-Left Pseudolanguage)

If you only do this step, the RTL layout will appear correctly in the simulator but not on a real device (unless the device's language is RTL)

2. Set the locale language

This will force the app's preferred language to always remain your RTL language.

```
@main
struct AppName: App {

    init() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).