# SwiftUI Picker Options Flipped in RTL

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-picker

As you can see in the attached image, the picker options are not aligned automatically to the right-hand side for RTL languages, and also flipped.

[image]

The picker is nothing fancy either, the standard way.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedDay: String = "יום שבת"
    private let days: [String] = ["יום שבת", "יוֹם רִאשׁוֹן", "יוֹם שֵׁנִי"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedDay) {
            ForEach(days, id: \.self) { day in
                Text(day).tag(day)
            }
        } label: {
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the development localization to Hebrew so RTL alignments are automatically done.

I have tried to force the alignment with

```
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

but nothing has worked.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)` should do this, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Could this answer for a similar problem with menus help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802086/123632

Comment: @AshleyMills I've tried that. If used on the picker itself it flips the selected string, but when used on the text within the foreach loop it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AshleyMills I've already seen the post in the link you shared. I've copy-pasted it in my project as a new file and nothing changed - selected text has the correct alignment, picker options don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this question seems a year later since I asked it XD. I have managed to get it to work in RTL :

1. Edit scheme > App Language > Arabic (or your RTL language or 'Right-to-Left Pseudolanguage')

If you only do this step, the RTL layout will appear correctly in the simulator but not on a real device (unless the device's language is RTL)

2. Set the locale language

This will force the app's preferred language to always remain your RTL language.

```
@main
struct AppName: App {

    init() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```